# Alternative to closing php tag and entering straight HTML when echo doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I apologize in advance for the horrible title; I'm sure there's a better way to ask this question, but I couldn't come up with it. I'll try to do a better job with an example.

I was recently working on a project in Wordpress using Woocommerce, and needed to create a shortcode in my functions.php file. This was a custom shortcode to display Woocommerce product "cards", each of which needing to be wrapped with a link around them. My issue arose when trying to echo out a link using `the_permalink()`. What kept happening was the permalink was being displayed on the front end, rather than simply linking the content that I wanted to link. I've heard that this problem can arise when using `echo` sometimes, although I'm not exactly sure why. Aside from all that, the code worked fine. However, due to the link displaying like it was, I ended up having to use this code:

```
echo '<div class="featured-products-carousel owl-theme owl-carousel">';
    if ( $products_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $products_query->have_posts() ) : $products_query->the_post();
            $thumb_image = kdmfi_get_featured_image_src( 'featured-image-2', 'full' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="featured-link">
                <div class="featured-product">
                    <div class="featured-img">
                        <?php
                        if ( isset($thumb_image) ) {
                            kdmfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'full');
                        } else {
                            echo ('<img width="300" height="300" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/woocommerce-placeholder.png" class="cat-thumbnail-img cat-placeholder-img" alt="Category Placeholder Image">');
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-text">
                        <div class="featured-product-title"><?php woocommerce_template_loop_product_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="featured-product-price"><?php woocommerce_template_single_price(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
echo '</div>';
```

You'll see that on the same line where I declare the variable `$thumb_image,` I had to close php so that I could use straight HTML for `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">`. Originally, I was trying to do it by not closing php and using `echo` before all my HTML tags, but then I ran into the issue I explained above. Therefore, my question is three-fold:

1. Why does `echo` display `the_permalink()`, rather than just linking it? I also tried `get_the_permalink()` as well, with the same results.
2. Is there a better way to get around this problem so that you don't need to close php and then reopen it after your HTML? Or is closing php in this situation and doing what I did best practice? It just seems like there should be a better way.
3. Where else might `echo` cause problems like the one I ran into? Is there a clear set of situations where using `echo` should be avoided in lieu of something else? If so, what are those situations?

Please let me know if any further information is necessary or would be helpful to have in order to answer my questions.

Thank you!

Comment: If this code you shared is what you're using with your shortcode: you're supposed to `return` a string, not `echo` it (see the [Shortcode API documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more details.) Also, it's [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) :P

Comment: _“Or is closing php in this situation and doing what I did best practice?”_ - it often makes for much more readable code, plus it eliminates the hassles you often have to deal with regarding escaping of string delimiters, when you output HTML via `echo`. If a large portion of the code is static HTML, that only needs dynamic values inserted in specific positions, then yes, I would say this is usually the best practice approach to follow.

Comment: When you have to _return_ a string value, instead of creating output directly (as @cabrerahector mentioned, is necessary when working with shortcodes), then you can not that easily just mix PHP and HTML though. But instead of using complex string concatenation then (same as you would with echo), it is often preferable to make use of output buffering then - then you can mix HTML & PHP again in the way that _would_ create direct output, but by using the buffer, you can capture it. You can find an easy example of how that works here, https://gist.github.com/facelordgists/8698928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the CODEX documentation:

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `the_permalink( int|WP_Post $post )` | [**Displays** the permalink for the current post.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) |
| `get_permalink( int|WP_Post $post, bool $leavename = false )` | [**Retrieves** the full permalink for the current post or post ID.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) |

The difference is subtile. `the_permalink` is used to **DISPLAY** the current post permalink and `get_permalink` is used to **RETRIEVE** it.

In Wordpress, functions starting with `the_` are a a container for the same `get_` version. They `the_ version` echo`-it out and sanitize it.

You never `echo` something that is already `echo`-ed out.